# To get count of a row with particular condition

Tags: php, sql

I want to get count of a row it exists in table.

```
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|100|a   |
+---+----+
|201|b   |
+---+----+
|302|c   |
+---+----+
|403|d   |
+---+----+
|504|e   |
+---+----+
```

In the above table i want to get output as 4(i.e) the count of that row exists. I have **'d'** value and have to write a query to get the output as 4 **where name = d**

I think code will be something like the below,

```
select count(*) ......
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing and makes no sense. How the count will be 4 if name = 'b' in the above table?

Comment: Do you want name=d or name=b?

Comment: In that case you must check my answer below :)

Comment: @Naveen: thats d and not b. Please give me the query i am not able to get it..

Comment: So you are looking for row number of "d"?

Comment: @Vinoth Babu check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) FROM yourtable WHERE name='d'
```

MySQL version

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT   @rank := @rank+1 AS rank
FROM     yourtable WHERE name='d'
ORDER BY id asc
```

Comment: Its throwing the following error.. 
"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY id)"

Comment: this was only meant as reference. Corrected the query.

Comment: So you are using MySQL. Not sure if row number will work there.

Comment: i have given same query dud.. I am getting the same error only. :(

Comment: SET @rank=0;
SELECT   @rank := @rank+1 AS rank
FROM     yourtable WHERE name='d'
ORDER BY id asc

Comment: that returns 1 only.. :(

Answer (score 0):

To get the Row Number

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) from table WHERE name='d'
```

To get the row count with your condition use below query

```
select count(*) as count from table where name = 'b'
```

Comment: where is the table name in first query?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correctly understand you this query is what you want:

```
set @row_number = 0; 
select @row_number := @row_number + 1 as row_number,name FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

@vinoth I think @Pragmatist Answer would work for you. Just add this clause to his query :

```
set @row_number = 0; 
select @row_number := @row_number + 1 as row_number,name FROM table_name Where name='b';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. MS SQL is a tested query, i just converted into mysql. Hope you can modify as per your requirement.

```
    SET @rank=0;
    SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN(
           SELECT   @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, ID
           FROM     Table1
           ORDER BY id asc) temp ON temp.ID = T1.ID
    WHERE T1.name = 'd'
```

MS SQL Query will be

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN(SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by id) AS RowNumber from Table1) temp ON   temp.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T1.name = 'd'
```